# Issues with sum and relatives parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum, size

I have a problem with my code and I hope you can help me.

I have a form in which you have to select the maximum size of a Disk and the relatives Disk's numbers.
The sum of each disk's numbers can't be greater than the size of the relative disk. (Please see the image)

[image: image explanation of the problem. 2 DISKs]

I tried lot of things but I problems with the form (classes, query etc).

```js
function check_number23() {
  let ProjectName = document.getElementById("resultsprojectname").innerHTML;

  var sizediskN1 = document.getElementsByClassName("sizediskN1");


  var value = Object.keys(sizediskN1).length;

  var disksizeN = document.getElementsByClassName("disksizeN");
  var disksizeNkey = Object.keys(disksizeN).length;



  for (var h = 0; h < value; h++) {
    var storagevalue = +sizediskN1[h].value;
  }
  alert(storagevalue);



  for (var j = 0; j < disksizeNkey; j++) {
    var storagemax = document.getElementsByClassName("disksizeN")[j].value;

    if (storagevalue - storagemax <= 0) {
      result = storagevalue + " GiB of Standard Partitions can be used.";
      document.getElementsByClassName("negativenumberchecker23")[h].innerHTML = result;
    } else {
      result = storagevalue + " GiB of Standard Partitions can't be used. Insert a new value.";
      alert(result);
      sizediskN1[h].value = '0';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Disk Size (GiB)</label> <input class="form-control disksizeO" type='number' min="1" onchange="check_numberDSKSizeO(this)" name='disksizeO[]' oninput="validity.valid||(value='0');" value='0' />
<label>Size (GiB):</label>
<input type='number' min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='0' onchange=" check_number23(this) " name='sizediskN1[]'  class='sizediskN1 form-control'>
```

I hope my problem is clear... Please help..

Comment: can you create a working snippet (edit the one above) so that we can help debug your code?

Comment: You are also missing `);"` on your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little snippet that checks values from two disks, and compares them to the total disk space available.

Please note, that it has to be modified to work with ANY number of size inputs and with ANY number of disks.

```js
const inpDiskSize = document.getElementById('disk-size')
const inpSize1 = document.getElementById('size1')
const inpSize2 = document.getElementById('size2')
let checkDisplay = true

// checking values and returning TRUE/FALSE
const checkValues = (dSize, sizeArr) => {
  return dSize >= sizeArr.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

// transforming data from UI to the checking function
const changeEvent = (inpDiskSize, inpSizeArr) => {
  return checkValues(inpDiskSize.value, inpSizeArr.map(e => Number(e.value) || 0))
}

// displaying text
const displayText = (d) => {
  let r = ''
  if (d) {
    r = "You can have these partitions."
  } else {
    r = "You can NOT have these partitions."
  }
  document.getElementById('checkDisplay').textContent = r
}

// change event listener registrations
inpDiskSize.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  displayText(changeEvent(inpDiskSize, [inpSize1, inpSize2]))
})
inpSize1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  displayText(changeEvent(inpDiskSize, [inpSize1, inpSize2]))
})
inpSize2.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  displayText(changeEvent(inpDiskSize, [inpSize1, inpSize2]))
})
```

```html
<label>Disk Size (GiB)</label>
<input id="disk-size" class="form-control disksizeO" type='number' min="1" name='disksizeO[]' oninput="validity.valid||(value='0');" value='0' />
<br />
<label>Size1 (GiB):</label>
<input id="size1" type='number' min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='0')" name='sizediskN1[]' class='sizediskN1 form-control' />
<br />
<label>Size2 (GiB):</label>
<input id="size2" type='number' min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='0')" name='sizediskN1[]' class='sizediskN1 form-control' />
<br />
<br />
<div id="checkDisplay"></div>
```

## EDIT

I suggested that this should/could be solved differently.

Here's the snippet:

```js
const msgArr = [
  'You can NOT have this configiration',
  'You can have this configiration'
]

// array of disk objects
const disks = [{
  diskId: 0,
  maxSize: 5,
  rels: [{
    size: 1
  }, {
    size: 2
  }],
  msg: 'You can have this configiration'
}, {
  diskId: 1,
  maxSize: 3,
  rels: [{
    size: 3
  }, {
    size: 4
  }],
  msg: 'You can NOT have this configiration'
}]

// displaying the disks (creating an HTML template and
// appending it to the DOM)
function render(disks) {
  let html = ''
  disks.forEach(disk => {
    html += `<h4>DISK ${disk.diskId}</h4>`
    html += `<label for="disk-${disk.diskId}">disk-${disk.diskId}<input id="disk-${disk.diskId}" class="size-input" data-diskId="${disk.diskId}" type="number" value="${disk.maxSize}"/></label><br />`
    disk.rels.forEach((rel, i) => {
      const relId = `disk-${disk.diskId}-rel-${i}`
      html += `<label for="${relId}">${relId}<input id="${relId}" class="disk-rel size-input" data-diskId="${disk.diskId}" data-relId="${i}" type="number" value="${rel.size}"/></label><br />`
    })
    html += '<br />'
    html += `<div class="message">${disk.msg}</div>`
    html += '<br />'
  })
  document.getElementById('disksContainer').innerHTML = html
  addEventListenersToInputs('.size-input')
}

// rendering the disks first time
render(disks)

// adding event listeners to input fields
function addEventListenersToInputs(selector) {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  inputs.forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      const diskId = this.getAttribute('data-diskId')
      updateValues(diskId, disks)
      render(disks)
    })
  })
}

// checking a single disk
function checkValue(disk) {
  return disk.rels.reduce((a, c) => a + Number(c.size), 0) <= disk.maxSize
}

// mutate the disks object
function updateValues(diskId, disks) {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-diskId="${diskId}"]`)
  const disk = disks.find(e => {
    return Number(e.diskId) === Number(diskId)
  })

  els.forEach(el => {
    if (el.getAttribute('id') === `disk-${disk.diskId}`) {
      disk.maxSize = el.value
    } else {
      disk.rels[Number(el.getAttribute('data-relId'))].size = el.value
    }
  })
  disk.msg = msgArr[Number(checkValue(disk))]
}
```

```html
<div id="disksContainer"></div>
```

The main difference with the previous solution is that the disks are note set in the DOM, but they are "kept" in a JavaScript array of objects. The HTML displayed is a JS "template" that is appended to the DOM - you can change it easier (the JS is not fully decoupled from the DOM, though).

This solution works with ANY number of disks containing ANY number of related partitions.

The code may be a bit longer than the first solution and seem to have more complexity, but it's because the HTML was put in the JS, and it had to work with multiple/any number of disks.

## EDIT 2

And then there's something completely different: a modern JS framework.

### VueJS

```js
Vue.component('disk', {
  props: ['disk'],
  data() {
    return {
      valid: 1,
      msg: [
        'You can NOT have this configuration.',
        'You can have this configuration.'
      ]
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="$emit('remove-disk', disk.id)">REMOVE DISK</button><br />
      <input type="number" :value="disk.maxSize" @change="setValue($event.target.value, 0)"/><button @click="addRel()">Add rel</button><br />
      <div :key="rel.id" v-for="rel in disk.rels">
        <input type="number" :value="rel.size" @change="setValue($event.target.value, rel.id)"/><button @click="removeRel(disk.id, rel.id)">REMOVE THIS REL</button>
      </div><br />
      {{msg[valid]}}
    </div>`,
  methods: {
    setValue(val, relId) {
      const emitVal = {
        val: val,
        diskId: this.disk.id,
        relId: relId
      }
      this.$emit('set-value', emitVal)
      this.valid = this.checkValues()
    },
    checkValues() {
      return Number(this.disk.rels.reduce((a, c) => {
        return a + Number(c.size)
      }, 0) <= this.disk.maxSize)
    },
    addRel() {
      this.$emit('add-rel', this.disk.id)
    },
    removeRel(diskId, relId) {
      this.$emit('remove-rel', {
        diskId,
        relId
      })
      this.valid = this.checkValues()
    }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    disks: []
  },
  methods: {
    addDisk() {
      const newDisk = {
        id: Date.now(),
        maxSize: 0,
        rels: []
      }
      this.disks.push(newDisk)
    },
    addRel(id) {
      this.disks.find(e => e.id === id)
        .rels.push({
          id: Date.now(),
          size: 0
        })
    },
    removeDisk(id) {
      this.disks = this.disks.filter(e => e.id !== id)
    },
    removeRel({
      diskId,
      relId
    }) {
      const disk = this.disks.find(e => e.id === diskId)
      disk.rels = disk.rels.filter(e => e.id !== relId)
    },
    setValue({
      val,
      diskId,
      relId
    }) {
      const disk = this.disks.find(e => e.id === diskId)
      if (relId === 0) {
        disk.maxSize = val
      } else {
        const rel = disk.rels.find(e => e.id === relId)
        rel.size = val
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="addDisk">ADD DISK</button>
  <div v-for="disk in disks">
    <disk :key="disk.id" :disk="disk" @add-rel="addRel($event)" @set-value="setValue($event)" @remove-disk="removeDisk($event)" @remove-rel="removeRel($event)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is fully dynamic <strike>(OK, no remove items)</strike>: handles any number of disks with any number of partitions.

## EDIT 3

I added the **remove disk** and **remove rel** functions - as asked for in a comment below.

Comment: that's almost perfect! But what if I have multiple "Disk Size(GiB)" and their relatives "Size's"?

Comment: Actually, I'd do it on a different base. I create an edited snippet, so you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I really love you! You saved me!! I really liked the Vue.js solution. I tried to implement a remove button for the new "Rels" but at the moment it is not working. I followed an example like this (https://jsbin.com/hihukavavi/edit?html,js,output) Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I added the **remove disk** and **remove rel** functions (in the Vue version). I placed it in the component and just **$emit()** events. The parent component handles the disks and rels array, and the modification "precipitates" down to the child component via the props.

Comment: The example you linked is OK, but it doesn't handle parent- and child components - everything happens in one place.